# MySQL : INSERT INTO from a cte with a JOIN

Tags: mysql

As a follow up from my "FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE fail in MySQL query" question, I have the following neat query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT `Ticker`,
       MIN(`trade_ID`) AS first_trade,
       MIN(`Price`) AS min_price,
       MAX(`Price`) AS max_price,
       MAX(`trade_ID`) AS last_trade
    FROM `Hist_price`
    WHERE `Time` >= 1683469229380 AND `Time` < 1683469349380
    GROUP BY Ticker
)

SELECT cte.*, h1.price AS open_price, h2.price AS close_price
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

But in fact, I want to INSERT IT in my result table.
I have tried to replace the last bit (from SELECT cte.*) with

```
INSERT INTO `calc_kline_1s` (Ticker, First_trade_id, First_trade_t, Last_trade_id, Last_trade_t, Low_p, High_p, Open_p, Close_p)                        
SELECT cte.*, h1.`price` AS open_price, h2.`price` AS close_price
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

```
INSERT INTO `calc_kline_1s` (Ticker, First_trade_id, First_trade_t, Last_trade_id, Last_trade_t, Low_p, High_p, Open_p, Close_p)                       
SELECT cte.Ticker,cte.first_trade,cte.first_trade_t,cte.last_trade,cte.last_trade_t,cte.min_price,cte.max_price, h1.`price` AS open_price, h2.`price` AS close_price
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

```
INSERT INTO `calc_kline_1s` (Ticker, First_trade_id, First_trade_t, Last_trade_id, Last_trade_t, Low_p, High_p, Open_p, Close_p)                       
VALUES (cte.Ticker,cte.first_trade,cte.first_trade_t,cte.last_trade,cte.last_trade_t,cte.min_price,cte.max_price, h1.`price` AS open_price, h2.`price` AS close_price)
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

but neither option work. Am I missing somthing. It usually works fine.
What am I missing this time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax :

```
INSERT INTO calc_kline_1s
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT `Ticker`,
       MIN(`trade_ID`) AS first_trade,
       MIN(`Price`) AS min_price,
       MAX(`Price`) AS max_price,
       MAX(`trade_ID`) AS last_trade
    FROM `Hist_price`
    WHERE `Time` >= 1683469229380 AND `Time` < 1683469349380
    GROUP BY Ticker
)
SELECT cte.Ticker,cte.first_trade, cte.first_trade, cte.last_trade,cte.last_trade, cte.min_price,cte.max_price, h1.`price`, h2.`price`
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

PS : *first_trade* and *last_trade* have been used twice since *first_trade_t* and *last_trade_t* are not exits

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FidH2dxZ)